# Changing value of slider by clicking on images

Tags: jquery, html, css, jquery-ui-slider

I want make value of slider change dynamically by clicking on images, example when i click on the first image the value of horizontal slider should be 1, the same think with the second image, my solution was to make an input hidden to save the position of image and put this value (positionimgvalue) in the value of horizontal slider but it doesn't work

this is my code  :

### HTML CODE :

```
<h1>Changing value of slider by clicking on images </h1>
<div id="slider"></div>

<p>Your slider has a value of <span id="slider-value"></span></p>
<input type=hidden name=value value="">
 <ul class="teintestyle">
<li>
 <img border="0" src="http://lorempixel.com/100/81/" width="100" height="81" alt="1" />
</li>

<li>
<img border="0" src="http://lorempixel.com/g/400/200" width="100" height="81" alt="2" />
</li>

<li>
<img border="0" src="http://lorempixel.com/400/200/sports" width="100" height="81" alt="3" />
</li>
<li>
<img border="0" src="http://lorempixel.com/400/200/sports/Dummy-Text" width="100" height="81" alt="4" />

</li>
</ul>
```

### JS code :

```
 $('.teintestyle li').click(function(){

          var value = ( $(this).find('img').attr('alt'));


         $( "input[name='value']" ).val(value);


     });
var positionimgvalue =  $( "input[name='value']" ).val();
$("#slider").slider(
{
            value:positionimgvalue,
            min: 0,
            max: 4,
            step: 1,
            slide: function( event, ui ) {
                $( "#slider-value" ).html( ui.value );
            }
}
);

$( "#slider-value" ).html(  $('#slider').slider('value') );
```

### jsfiddle :

[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/5TTm4/2939/)

THANKS FOR HELP

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use index() for each li instead of getting attr('alt')

```
 $('.teintestyle li').click(function(i){   
         var value = $(this).index();
         $('#slider-value').text(value);
         $('#slider').slider('value', value);
     });
```

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/5TTm4/2942/)

Comment: Thank you that's what i want exactly

Answer (score 2):

I am not sure what you want. May be you want to change slider dynamically when click on image. I have added only one line for changing value pragmatically :

```
$('#slider').slider('value', value);// changing value of slider
```

[**Updated DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/5TTm4/2940/) See changing slider value when click on images

Comment: that what i want exactly but it still another probleme the text "Your slider has a value of 1' didn't change how i can fixe that  thank you so mush

Comment: to be fair .. you are faster than me .. +1 for fast answer :)

Answer (score 0):

Please note the below fiddle to answer - although it fixes your problem - is definately NOT the way to do this.

using an alt to store a value is not correct as alt tags are to help describe what the image is.

Instead look-up data- attributes as this is what they are designed for.

```
 $('.teintestyle li').click(function(){

      var val1 = ( $(this).find('img').attr('alt'));


 $("#slider").slider({'value':val1}); // set the value of the slider
 $( "#slider-value" ).html(  $('#slider').slider('value') ); //update the text
 });
```

[Fiddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/5TTm4/2941/)

Answer (score -1):

Just add

```
$('#slider-value').text(value);
```

after

```
 $( "input[name='value']" ).val(value);
```

The input is hidden, of course you couldn't see it.